# Audio Recorder not saving files on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: audio-recording

I just installed Audio recorder from Ubuntu software centre on my Ubuntu 18.04 system, everything looks to be working, start record, stop record, even shows recording on the level indicator. When I stop recording and go to the save folder, there are no files.

Comment: Are you referring to `gnome-sound-recorder` [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/gnome-sound-recorder)?

Comment: Hi Believe so, but it is Audio Recorder, installed it from Ubuntu software centre. all looks to be working just no saved file generated

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by uninstalling and reinstalling through the terminal, for some reason I wasn't able to select the audio source through refresh.